# Can user resume a conversation in a different channel? (Bot Framework)

Tags: botframework

Let's think of the following example:

1) I have a certain bot deployed on Azure

2) Bot can be talked via Facebook Messenger and via Skype

3) A certain user talks to the bot via Facebook Messenger and then he leaves.

4)A couple of minutes ago the same user resumes the conversation with the bot, but via Skype.

Is this possible? I assume Bot Framework doesn't have anything included for this, hence, that this isn't posible (as conversations are independent and state changes depending on the channel). Is there any way to identify a user (via some authentication method maybe), and then making this logic again?

Do any of you know any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework Connector service is a component which provides a single API for your bot to communicate across multiple client services such as Skype, Email, Slack. Every bot and user has an account within each channel.

The channel account contains an identifier (id) and other informative bot non-structural data, like an optional name.

And there us unique conversation ID created for each conversation of each user for each channel. And you can customize your channel capabilities as described [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html).

Regards,

Jyo